# Famous problem of Francesco Galigai

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Apparently the Italian mathematician has noticed in *Pratica di arithmetica* :

> Every rational number of the form $n=\frac{(q+1)^2}{q+2}$ satisfies the equation $n-\left(\frac{q}{q+1}\right)n=\frac{q+1}{q+2}$, for all integer $q\ne\{-1,-2\}$.

Could anyone have references ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: There is no integer of that form

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It is clear that $\gcd(q+1,q+2)=1$, no?  So your expression $n$ can't be an integer.  What did you intend?

Comment: Also:  $n-\left( \frac 1{q+1}\right)n= \frac n{q+1}$ so it is a triviality that your equations are equivalent .  Voting to close the question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust my mistake the number $n\in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @lulu my mistake I wrote too fast. We have $n\in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ok but I cannot find Galigai's work, maybe there are some generalizations...

Comment: as it stands the statement is a complete triviality, so there is nothing to generalize.

Comment: @lulu It's so unfortunate then...

Comment: @YvesDaoust These last days in a book of 7th grade http://enseignants.nathan.fr/catalogue/transmath-4e-livre-de-l-eleve-9782091719160.html

It was an example with $q=2$ and the reference was Galigai's problem.

Comment: @YvesDaoust And in this same powerful book there are military problems of not well-known mathematician. Just amazing !

Comment: @YvesDaoust Look at Francés Pellos's problem on spears impressive :o

Comment: @YvesDaoust there is no need to be so mean and arrogant... If you find these problems super easy, good for you, but at that period people like soldiers or sellers did not have access to knowledge and education (XV-th century). It was a progress to explain to them that kind of problem with the method of "false approach". Even now students meet difficulties to solve that kind of statement.

Answer (score 2):

Just simplify the left-hand side of the equation, substitute $n = \dfrac{(q+1)^2}{q+2}$ into it, and simplify some more:

$$ n - \frac q{q+1}n = n\left(1 - \frac q{q+1}\right) = n \cdot \frac 1{q+1} = \frac{(q+1)^2}{q+2} \cdot \frac1{q+1} = \frac{q+1}{q+2}
$$

Comment: Thank you I know how to solve the statement, I was just wondering if there was references because I could not find Galigai's work.

Comment: @Maman, you should edit your question to make it clear you're looking for a reference.